# Is there any way to launch a Genymotion emulator with the screen already unlocked?

Tags: android, jenkins, genymotion

Our team recently setup Genymotion for a Jenkins instance using the instructions [here](http://blog.genymobile.com/genymotion-jenkins-android-testing/).  Everything is working awesome except for functional tests, which use Robotium.

It seems that the instrumentation can't figure out how to unlock the device, which means that it is unable to find the necessary UI elements for our functional tests, causing them all to fail.

I've tried taking a snapshot of an unlocked device, restoring that snapshot, and then launching the emulator with Genymotion.  However, when I do that, Genymotion gives me an error on start saying that the device is in an incompatible state and then the Jenkins run fails.

So, I'm wondering is there any way to either programatically unlock the screen or launch a Genymotion emulator such that the screen is already unlocked?

EDIT: The tests are targeting API level 10 phones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered the solution was to add this line to our Jenkins pre-execute script.

`adb shell input keyevent 82`

This simulates a press of the menu key, which removes the lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need lock to show up, simply disable screen lock in emulate device's settings. Setting is persistent.

**EDIT**

There are tools like No Lock ([Google Play link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jraf.android.nolock)) that may be helpful in your case. I checked using Genymotion with API10 image (Nexus S) and it does the trick

Comment: The best I can find on the emulator is to set "screen unlock security" to None which doesn't solve the problem since a lock screen still shows up.

Comment: We talk about the same? Android settings -> security -> screen lock -> none? Once I set it to none. screen lock is gone

Comment: This works on phones with API level > 10 (I tested on one with API 19), but not on phones with API level 10.  Setting the security option to "none" on API level 10 just defaults to slide.

We're trying to run our tests on a phone with API level 10 unfortunately.

Comment: Tried using tools like NoLock? I linked in edited answer. It works for me on API 10

Comment: I actually solved this a separate way.  If you use the adb shell you can input `adb shell input keyevent 82` which will input a "menu" key event to the emulator, causing the lock screen to go away.